# Error configuring application listener of class

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to migrate my application from jboss 6.0 to jboss 7.1 but I am getting the following error at deployement time.

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ns]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error configuring application listener of class com.bowebellhowell.winsort.scheme.service.SessionListen: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bowebellhowell.winsort.scheme.service.SessionListen from [Module "deployment.nsserver.ear.nsweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3342) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb 7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]


ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ns]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
15:04:09,288 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart
15:04:09,288 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context [/ns] startup failed due to previous errors
15:04:09,292 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ns: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ns: JBAS018040: Failed to start context at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95) at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

please resolve as i am stuck at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Class loading it little bit different in jboss7.

Where you placed jars? you can take a look at below link for more details

[Class Loading in AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7)

Comment: Link-only answer with no substantial content. If the link goes down the answer becomes useless. Downvote until fixed.